# What should I connect when creating a relationship between 2 tables?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

For example I have 2 tables namely parent table and children table

**Parent table**

`parent_id`

`name`

Then I have **Children table**

`children_id`

`name`

Then a **Relationship Table**

`relationship_id`

`child_id`

`father_id` or `father_name?`

`mother_id` or `mother_name?`

If I want to create a relationship between 2 tables that indicates the `parents` of the `children` what should I link?

Should I create a field named for example a `father_id` to get the unique id of the parent or `father_name` to get a direct link for the name of the father in **Relationship table** if I want to get the name of the father?

Comment: Why do you need a relationship table at all? do you expect a child to have more then one father or more then one mother? what happens when the child grows and have children of his own? would you replicate it's data from the children table to the parents table?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's just a brief example in order to apply my question. But my main concern is regarding whether to use `parent_id` or `parent_name` to directly link it to the name of the parents.

Comment: You should (and at least in some if not all databases that's your only option anyway) always use the primary keys for relationships. At least one side of the relationship needs to be connected to the table's primary key.

Comment: BTW, For the example you wrote, I would go with a single person table, that will hold the following columns:
Person_Id, Person_FirstName, Person_LastName, Person_Mother_Id, Person_Father_Id.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good proposal for an answer. Maybe you should make that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (and at least in some if not all databases that's your only option anyway) always use the primary keys for relationships.
At least one side of the relationship needs to be connected to the table's primary key.

However, for the example you wrote, I would go with a single person table:

```
TblPerson
(
    Person_Id, -- Primary key
    Person_FirstName, 
    Person_LastName, 
    Person_Mother_Id, -- Self reference FK
    Person_Father_Id -- Self reference FK
)
```